# spring jdbcTemplate do I still need a PreparedStatement?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

using spring jdbc I have the update() convenience method for inserting data in the DB.

So I don't need anymore the PreparedStatement stuff??

Is that correct? Or there are situation where I still may need those statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a `PreparedStatement` for performance reasons if you had some SQL that was being executed repeatedly. A `PreparedStatement` also allows for clean parameter substitution within the SQL (rather than doing string concatenation).

Otherwise, for quick and simple insert/update/delete statements, then the convenience `JdbcTemplate.update(String)` methods may be your best choice.